# Java class definition: what does "<>" mean?

Tags: java

Here is the class definition in java code:

```
public class WordCount {

 public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
 }
```

So what does this mean?

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
```

Why we need a "<>" here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "generics". It allows you to add type parameters.

In this particular case, it means that `Map` is a `Mapper` for tuples of (LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable).

A simpler example: suppose you have a Set. It could be a Set of integers, a set of strings, of MyClass instances.... this is where you use generics.
By declaring that a variable is of type `Set<Integer>`, you specify that it is a set of Integers. If you'd just declare it as a Set, you would have to check that it only contained Integers yourself. By adding the type parameter `<Integer>`, the compiler can now do the type-checking.

Generics are defined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.1.2) in the Java Language Specification.

Comment: So it means I cannot use Map with tuples other than (LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable), for example (int, int, int, int). Right?

Comment: Exactly. The compiler will catch that for you. Of course there's nothing keeping you from instantiating a `Mapper<Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer>` if you need that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the declaration of your `Mapper` class. It is possibly something like that `class Mapper<E, T, T, K>` which declares 3 different **generic types**.